# How to expand/collapse groups using PrimeNG?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm simply trying to add 2 buttons to **expand** and **collapse** all groups in my code using primeNG. Here's my working code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/U5T5U3J3Z8PzlHRHaOuw?p=preview)

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" sortField="room" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="room" expandableRowGroups="true"
    [sortableRowGroup]="false">
 <ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData.room}} - INFO</ng-template>
 <p-column field="status" header="ID"></p-column>
 <p-column field="name" header="Title"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expandedRowsGroups` property and assign it an array containing the group headers to be displayed or not.

> expandedRowsGroups : Collection of group field values to show a group as expanded by default.

---

Fill or unfill `expandedGroups` array when clicking on the buttons :

```
  expandAll() {
    this.expandedGroups = [];
    this.expandedGroups.push('ROOM1');
    this.expandedGroups.push('ROOM2');
    this.expandedGroups.push('ROOM3');
  }

  collapseAll() {
    this.expandedGroups.pop('ROOM1');
    this.expandedGroups.pop('ROOM2');
    this.expandedGroups.pop('ROOM3');
  }
```

And relevant buttons :

```
<button (click)="expandAll()">Expand all</button>
<button (click)="collapseAll()">Collapse all</button>
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fIjMQplAsdkTvxoR3iDs?p=preview)

Comment: How would you expand them by default? I mean when page loads the first time I want them to be expanded

Comment: @progx Call expandAll method in the constructor (see new version of my Plunker)

Answer (score 1):

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="data" sortField="room" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="room" rowGroupExpandMode="multiple" expandableRowGroups="true"
        [sortableRowGroup]="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData.room}} - INFO</ng-template>
    <p-column field="status" header="ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Title"></p-column>

</p-dataTable>


<button type="button" pButton (click)="expandAll(dt)" label="Expand All"></button>


<button type="button" pButton (click)="collapseAll(dt)" label="Collapse All"></button>
```

Notice adding the template reference #dt in the html along with rowGroupExpandMode="multiple"

```
expandAll(dt: DataTable) {
    dt['expandedRowsGroups'] = [];
    Object.keys(dt.rowGroupMetadata).forEach((row)=>{
       dt['expandedRowsGroups'].push(row);
    });
}

expandAll(dt: DataTable) {
    dt['expandedRowsGroups'] = [];
}
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/0o42Jb/

Comment: Can you provide a Plunker? Thanks

Comment: @progx I added a plunker,

Comment: It worked :)! do you by any chance know how to change the default arrow icon? When a row is expanded I want to use class="fa fa-minus-square" and when row is collapsed I want to use class="fa fa-plus-square" using font-awesome

Comment: Do this little hack to your component:  

styles: [`
    :host /deep/ .fa-chevron-circle-right:before {    content: "\\f0fe";}
    :host /deep/.fa-chevron-circle-down:before {content: "\\f147";}`
  ]